# SQLite iPhone error,

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am following through [this tutorial](http://icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/) and after completing it I am getting an error on build.
The error isn't associated with any line of source code though.
This is the error I get:

```
Line Location Tool:0: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Line Location Tool:0: symbol(s) not found
Line Location Tool:0: -[todo initWithPrimaryKey:database:] in todo.o
Line Location Tool:0: "_sqlite3_bind_init", referenced from:
```

I'm not sure what the error is.
The tutorial is building for the iPhone 2.0 framework but I am building for 3.0.
Their libsqlite3.0.dylib is from the iPhone 2.0 SDK whereas mine is from the 2.2.1 SDK (that's the newest version that is over 1mb)
I've tried the 2.0, 2.2.1 and 3.0 framework libsqlite3.0.dylib files, they all provide this same error.

Could anyone give me some advice on what to do here?  I've tried googling the error and I get nothing at all.
I was getting more errors similar to this one until I realized that I was using the libsqlite3.0.dylib from the OS X SDK not the iPhone SDK.  Once I switched that I only had this error left.

Comment: It's a typo. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196985/232821

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a typo.
sqlite3_bind_init was supposed to say:
sqlite3_bind_int

init vs int.

Oops!

Bye!